# How to incorporate user input into lookahead and lookbehind assertion in regex

Tags: python, regex, text, user-input, text-mining

How do I incorporate user input together with lookahead/lookbehind assertion in regex to obtain the context of the word?

```
user_term = input('Enter a term: ')
word = 'Hello, this is an autogenerated message. Do not reply'
res_bef = re.search('(\w+-?,?.?\s){3}(?=autogenerated)', word)
print(res_bef.group(0))
```

Currently, I'm manually changing this part of the code (?=autogenerated) to get the terms I want, but I want the code to be more flexible to take any user input.

Comment: What sorts of input does your current pattern match, and what change are you expecting here?

Answer (score 0):

You can format the user input in:

```
user_term = input('Enter a term: ')
word = 'Hello, this is an autogenerated message. Do not reply'
res_bef = re.search(r'(\w+-?,?.?\s){{3}}(?={user})'.format(user=user_term), word)
print(res_bef.group(0))
```